# htaccess: remove extension, and redirect to index.php?p=<page>

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I've got the previous code that rewrites  ex: domain.com/about to domain.com/index.php?page=about

So now, I want to add a measure of safety to that just in case someone adds .html or .php to the end thinking it should be there, I want it to remove the extension, but still follow my previous rule.  I want this change to ignore if the file actually exists.  If the file exists, it needs to still process the ending.

ex:

if someone types in about.php or about.html, I want it to remove the extension, and then process whats left to the rewrite rule above.

So about.php will rewrite to about and then rewrite to index.php?page=about

If at all possible, I'd like for it to actually change the URL to domain.com/about.  Right now, the above rewrite leaves the domain.com/about but just processes it through index.php.  I would love it if they enter about.php or about.html it would redirect the browser to domain.com/about .

Any way possible to achieve this?  I've looked around at removing file extension with htaccess, but none of them do what I want with redirecting to index.php?page=.  They all want to redirect differently.

### EDIT

I need this to be universal.  It can't just process 'about', I need it to process anything in that specific spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not a directory or a file, and it has an extension, then redirect without extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$   index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*)\..*$   $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: what about this do I need to modify.  I copied and pasted and it doesn't work.  I'm guessing something goes in the .., but maybe not.  I'm not the greatest with custom htaccess.

Comment: you just have to copy it (i edited my answer with your previous rule)

Comment: oh okay, I had it in the wrong place.  I put it above my rule.  Awesome, thanks!  Works like a charm