# How to I make my URL like index.php?page=Login

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm quite new in the web development scene so I am unsure and how to do this, and would like to learn how to do this.

Edit:
I am just basically trying to make it so when ever a user navigates to a different page instead of having http://www.example.com/[PAGE].php it to look like 
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=[PAGE]

Comment: this feels like it should be a dupe of a "Pretty Url" question... an answer is to have your index.php use `include $_GET['page'] . ".php";` ... but w/ more error checking and then have all the "Login" logic in some file called `Login.php` (similar for your other possible pages.)

Comment: How to find your answer using google = search for `"index.php?page=" site:stackoverflow.com`, I suspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127093/htaccess-remove-extension-and-redirect-to-index-phpp-page will answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your users navigate different pages by using links (`<a></a> tags`). If so, just change the href, like this:

```
<a href="?page=Login">this links redirects to the login page</a>
```

Then, to process the `GET` parameter you have in your link, just do as Haider Ali said.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
   $page = $_GET['page'];

   // process depending on $page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called the GET method, or GET request. You should read a bit about it.

To redirect to such a page, you just create an href that just looks the way you want it to.

Basically, it would be a GET request, and 'page' would be an attribute of the request that has a value.

To grab the value that comes along with it

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
   $page = $_GET['page'];
   echo $page;
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. I assume you're trying to link to another page after submitting data to login. Try to use "POST" in method action.

Comment: No sorry for the confusion but I am trying to make it so when ever a suer navigates to a page the URL will look like this
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=[PAGE NAME HERE]
The 2 different examples probably threw you off

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using a framework like CakePhp or Codeigniter.

Anyways to achieve what you're trying to do, you could do something like this in your index.php

```
  <?php
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];

if(isset($page)){
    include $page.".php"; // you could always get rid of the '.php' and pass it over the REQUEST or GET parameter
}else{
    die("Please provide a page to load");
}
 ?>
```